# How to have gantt chart using python or pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, gantt-chart

I'm working on a (asset management) system to handle assets , resources and progress of tasks
I want to have a gantt chart in my system

I'm using python 2.6 and pyqt . 
Is there any (already made charts python library)? that can work well with pyqt.

or should i make a custom widgets for this ? Please advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the [faces](http://faces.homeip.net/) project.  It uses little Python scripts to define tasks and dependencies, and generates a number of Gantt and other project management graphics.

Answer (score 1):

These are not pyQt related but you can have a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GanttPV/0.1

or maybe h[ttp://pypi.python.org/pypi/xm.charting/0.3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xm.charting/0.3)

I have not used any of them though so I can not give you more specific info.